# How to get Source code of html file and put in string

Tags: python, html

Is it possible to put In a variable a source code of an HTML file?

I mean, If I have `test.html`, so how can I take the source code of this html file and put it on a string ?

Answer (score 4):

Just open the file and read it:

```
f = open('test.html', 'r')
html_string = f.read()
f.close()
```

or

```
with open('test.html', 'r') as f:  # with can auto close the file like f.close() does
    html_string = f.read()
```